# How to update latitude/longitude in Android on google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an indoor location application where the latitude/longitude will be updated from gathered sensor data. I cannot find any API that assists with simply updating the latitude/longitude on a map as that is literally the only thing I want to do. I do not want to use GPS data as the intent of the application is for indoor locations where GPS signal is heavily challenged i.e. under ground parking. Did I maybe miss something in the google maps API that someone can point me too? I will be calculating the new latitude/longitude using old lat/lon data and the sensor data (accelerometer for example).

So long story short, I want to update the marker on the map using sensor data only and I cannot find a library function in the API that allows me to update latitude/longitude on the map. Is there anything that can do that based on the new latitude/longitude I calculate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should save a reference (1) of the marker that you first create, and then update (2) his location.

1)
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(firstLatLng));

2)
marker.setPosition(newLatLng);

Comment: This seems simple enough. I'll try implement this overnight with some sample data. Just to clarify, after I calculate my newLatLng I just plug it into the marker.setPosition() function and it should update on the map correct?

Comment: Yes, that will update your map marker. Also, if you want to move the map camera into this new location, you could do that with the mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(newLatLng)) method.

Comment: Hey, sorry for getting back so late. This solution worked wonderfully, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want to know more about updating all map features take a glance at [google map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/)

But, if you are running out of time and want a quick fix to your lattitude and longitude updates every time then have a look at this [receiving location updates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)